# Error while implementing Pop-Up Menu in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I am attempting to add a popup menu on Fragment using kotlin .

**The idea is ,when click the text "Hello World" ,the popup menu pops up**  ,

[image]

**the xml file** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragment.HomeFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
        <!--Selected option will display here-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/selectedTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="Hello World!" />



    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**The Fragment :**(I needed it a fragment .And this **fragment crash when the app launch** )

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        //init popup menu
        val popupMenu = PopupMenu(
            context,
            selectedTv
        )
        //add menu items to popup menu

        popupMenu.menu.add(Menu.NONE,0,0,"1")
        popupMenu.menu.add(Menu.NONE,1,1,"2")
        popupMenu.menu.add(Menu.NONE,2,2,"3")
        popupMenu.menu.add(Menu.NONE,3,3,"4")
        popupMenu.menu.add(Menu.NONE,4,4,"5")

        //handle menu clicks
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener {menuItem ->

            //get id of the item clicked
            val id = menuItem.itemId

            if(id==0){
                selectedTv.text = "1"

            }else if(id==1){
                selectedTv.text = "2"

            }else if(id==2){
                selectedTv.text = "3"

            }else if(id==3){
                selectedTv.text = "4"

            }else if(id==4){
                selectedTv.text = "5"

            }

            true



        }

        //handle button click,show menu
        selectedTv.setOnClickListener {
            popupMenu.show()
        }

        return v
    }


}
```

Not able to figure out why it is crashing , need help for the same.

Comment: Upload your error in your code

Comment: Hi ,KaruneshPalekar, here is the error Locat : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.gearsrun.popmenuapplication.fragment.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.kt:65)

Comment: The crash happens because selectedTv is null. This happens because the view is yet to set. Try to move the popup code to onViewCreated() method.

Comment: H i, gioravered! You saved me !! Thank you so much my friend !!!